# Feature selection by genetic algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithm, feature-detection, feature-selection, genetic-programming

I would like to explore feature selection using genetic algorithm, particularly areas of image processing, i.e. image recognition, fingerprint matching, edge detection, OCR etc. 
My questions are:
1.Is there any test image with which I can test my algorithm? 
2.Any suggestions about the design of fitness function?
Also any good webpage recommended?
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Wouldn't a proper test image depend entirely on what it is you're trying to test?  How could we possibly know what would be best suited for your needs?  For what concerns fitness, a good fitness function can quickly assess whether or not a solution is good or bad and reduce that assessment to a simple score.

Comment: The Q #1 is hard to answer without more information. Q#2: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

[Baboon](https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png) is one of the most used images in the field of image processing.

Answer (score 0):

for dataset visit https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html

for fitness function, firstly describe your problem: classification or regression? if classification, how many class? in general for classification problems maximizing (true detection/(false detection + 1)) is a good fitness function

also i think for feature extraction(selection) tasks, genetic programming led to better answers.